# Sort using awk?

Tags: sorting, text, awk

I have a file that starts with strings as follows

`x1, 1, 2, ...`

```
x2, 1, 2, ...

x10, 1, 3, ...

x22, 1, 3, ...

x14, 1, 2, ...
```

Is is possible to sort this file using awk, so that I get the output that is numerically sorted, e.g. lines starting with x1, followed by x2,.. and so on ?

Comment: I tried using sort -n, but it gives me x10, x1, and so on. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: If your version of `sort` supports it, use `sort -V` or `sort --version-sort`. If not and your prefix is always the same length (e.g. "x" is one character), try `sort -k1.2n -t,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, like Dennis said, your prefix is of fixed width, try using:

```
sort -k 1.2 -g -t,
```

In my case, using the sort that came with Mac OS X, I had to use the `-g` switch.

Comment: I tried using this option.  I am just wondering if you can explain how these options work?  I tried reading the man page, but it was not very illuminating.

Comment: The option -k allows you to skip some charts from the start of the line and start sorting after that. `-k 1.2` actually means start sorting after the second character of the first field.


In this case, each field is a value that is separated by comma. The `-t,` means field separator is ",".


And `-g` means to sort numerically (versus alphabetically, I guess).